# aws cognito custom scopes missing in an access-token

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, access-token, amazon-cognito

I've set up my aws cognito user pool with Authorization code grant flow and configured it to include custom scopes as well, but in the access tokens generated, these custom scopes are missing.

Appreciate any help on this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: This article offers some clues. https://lobster1234.github.io/2018/05/31/server-to-server-auth-with-amazon-cognito/ In my case, the app didn't include app secret, so I couldn't use the client credentials under Allowed OAuth Flows. Generating the token from CLI worked fine.